# Codeigniter populate multiselect with selected values using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, multi-select

I have a multiselect in one of my Modals that I would like to populate using jQuery/JavaScript created with the code below:

```
<select multiple class="selectpicker display-block" data-width="100%" name="non-compatibility[]" id="non-compatibility" title='<?php echo _l('invoice_suboption_noncompatible'); ?>'>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php foreach($suboptions as $suboption){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $suboption['plat_option'].','.$suboption['name']; ?>" data-subtext="<?php echo $suboption['plat_option']; ?>"><?php echo $suboption['name']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
```

The values look like RAM,4GB and HardDrive,1TB. I would like to set the selected values for the multiselect using jQuery/JavaScript but I'm having a hard time. I thought the below would work but it doesn't. `$('select[name="non-compatibility[]"]').val('RAM,4GB');`

Any clues what might be going on or how to do this successfully?

**EDIT**

I noticed That when I pick another option in the select manually it then shows the ones I set to selected. Is there some way that I have to refresh the select in order to show the change?

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you.

```js
$( '.selectpicker' ).multiselect();

$('.btn-set-val').click(function(){
  var tes = ['tes','ppp'];
  $( '.selectpicker' ).val(tes);
  $( '.selectpicker' ).multiselect( 'refresh' );
});

$('.btn-add-opt').click(function(){
  $( '.selectpicker' ).append("<option>new_opt</option>");
  $( '.selectpicker' ).multiselect( 'rebuild' );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>tes</option>
  <option>tesewew</option>
  <option>32tes</option>
  <option>te32esds</option>
  <option>ppp</option>
</select>

<button class='btn-set-val'>Set selected value</button>
<button class='btn-add-opt'>Add new option</button>
```